# Composer + local git repo: "could not be found in any version"

Tags: git, symfony, composer-php

I am working on a Symfony project using Composer to manage the dependencies. Some of the required packages are git repos that are located a special server. I can access this Server using Public Key but I cannot give others access to the same server.

Now I would like to let a partner work on the project as well. To let him access the packages they have to be stored on a more public location.

To achieve this I cloned the package repos to my own local machine and tried use them. I changed the `composer.json`:

```
...
"require": {
    ...
    "mycompany/commons":"dev-master",
    "mycompany/data":"dev-master",
    ...
},  
...

"minimum-stability": "stable",
"extra": {
    "symfony-app-dir": "app",
    "symfony-web-dir": "web",
    "branch-alias": {
        "dev-master": "1.8-dev"
    }
},

"repositories": [
    {
        "type": "vcs",
        "url": "ssh://git@my-restricted-server.x/commons.git"
    },
    {
        "type": "vcs",
        "url": "ssh://git@my-restricted-server.x/data.git"
    },
]
```

Changed to:

```
"repositories": [
    {
        "type": "vcs",
        "url": "file://absolut/path/to/commons/.git"
    },
    {
        "type": "vcs",
        "url": "file://absolut/path/to/data/.git"
    },
]
```

When I try to use composer to install I get the following error:

```
$ composer install --no-dev --optimize-autoloader

Loading composer repositories with package information
Installing dependencies                                          
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - The requested package mycompany/commons could not be found in any version, there may be a typo in the package name.
  Problem 2
    - The requested package mycompany/data could not be found in any version, there may be a typo in the package name.


Potential causes:
 - A typo in the package name
 - The package is not available in a stable-enough version according to your minimum-stability setting
   see <https://groups.google.com/d/topic/composer-dev/_g3ASeIFlrc/discussion> for more details.

Read <https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/troubleshooting.md> for further common problems.
```

I double checked the package name and the path and everything is fine. Any idea what might be wrong?

NOTE: I am trying to access/use the local git packages my self. Letting my partner access these packages would be the next step.

Comment: We need to see the composer files for those private repositories.  Make sure all remaining changes are committed and test again before editing.

Comment: Try `"url": "absolut/path/to/commons"` without `.git` and `file://`

Comment: @Peh Thank you! `.git` is required but deleting file:// did the trick.

Comment: wrote an answer to close this question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove `file://` from the `url`

```
"repositories": [
    {
        "type": "vcs",
        "url": "absolut/path/to/commons/.git"
    },
    {
        "type": "vcs",
        "url": "absolut/path/to/data/.git"
    },
]
```